# Django - Joining after filtering

Tags: django, performance, django-orm

Imagine there are a model and a view:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(...)
    message = models.TextField(...)
    performer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, ...)
    orgunit = models.ForeignKey(OrgUnit, on_delete=models.CASCADE ...)
    deviation = models.ForeignKey(Deviation, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='tasks', ...)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, ...)
    for_control = models.ManyToManyField('self', ...)
    # другие поля

class TasksViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = TaskSerializer
    pagination_class = TasksPaginator
    filterset_class = TasksFilterSet

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = Task.objects\
            .select_related(
                'performer__position__orgunit__conformation', 'deviation',
                'creator__position__orgunit__conformation', 'orgunit__conformation',
            ).prefetch_related('for_control')

        return qs
```

Fields in `select_related` and `prefetch_related` are for future serializing.

As far as I know first joining happens and then filtering (`where` clause from `TasksFilterSet`) happens, right? If so obviously this can affect performance.

So I thought would it be better first filter and then join? Of course some joins need to be done for filtering but this is not the case. I mean something like this:

```
class TasksViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = TaskSerializer
    pagination_class = TasksPaginator
    filterset_class = TasksFilterSet

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Task.objects.only('pk')

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)

        if page is not None:
            page = Task.objects.filter(pk__in=[task.pk for task in page]).select_related(
                'performer__position__orgunit__conformation', 'deviation',
                'creator__position__orgunit__conformation', 'orgunit__conformation',
            )
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

What do you think about this?

Comment: It doesn't matter when you call select_related and prefetch_related, before or after a filter, the query will not execute any differently.

Answer (score 0):

The order in which you call select_related(), prefetch_related() and filter() does not matter. The resulting queryset will be the same

From the docs for [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related)

> The order of filter() and select_related() chaining isn’t important. These querysets are equivalent:
>
> `Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__gt=timezone.now()).select_related('blog')
> Entry.objects.select_related('blog').filter(pub_date__gt=timezone.now())`

Comment: I'm asking not about order in queryset but about order of filtering and joining in Postgres. Imagine a raw SQL-query (no Django at all). In the query `where` clause and 5 joins. So what happens first - joining or filtering

Comment: @АльбертАлександров SQL queries have a specific structure, FROM (joins) has to come before WHERE. That's besides the point though, Django will generate the __same SQL__ no matter which order you call filter() and select_related()

Comment: You seem to be asking if executing 2 queries instead of 1 will improve performance?

Comment: @АльбертАлександров it depends on the query and the optimizations the query optimizer in the database decides to perform. If you want to look into this further [`explain()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.explain) should be your friend!